# how to make a modal in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I want to make a dialog element to edit events (an edit button is placed with each event) in a separate component. Is there a built-in way I can do this in svelte? I tried changing the display from none to block and vice versa but it keeps telling me 'dialog is null'. All of the youtube tutorials in this are too outdated, the packages do not exist on GitHub anymore.
While we're at it, is this the best practice for my situation or can it be improved?
I tried fixing the error with this code, the function is triggered but nothing happens

```
<script>
  let dialogRef;
  let showDialog = false;

  const editEvent = () => {
    if (dialogRef) {
      dialogRef.showModal();
      showDialog = true;
    }
  };

  const closeDialog = () => {
    dialogRef.close();
    showDialog = false;
  };
</script>

<main>
  {#if showDialog}
    <dialog on:cancel={closeDialog} bind:this={dialogRef}>
      <button class="close" on:click={closeDialog}>x</button>
      <p>content here</p>
    </dialog>
  {/if}
  <button on:click={editEvent}>Edit Event</button>
</main>

<style>
  dialog {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9999;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `showDialog` is `false`, the element does not exist because of the `#if`. To make sure that the element is always there, the easiest thing to do is not using `#if` but a conditional class, e.g. `class:hidden={!showDialog}`, which sets `display` to `none`. Though you should not need that at all, as the `dialog` should not be visible by default until its methods are called.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b815fe095446402398bca77ba7e55454?version=3.55.1)

Another approach would be to change the order of operations and wait for the element to be created.

```js
const editEvent = async () => {
    showDialog = true;
    await tick(); // from 'svelte', waits for the UI to update
    dialogRef.showModal();
};
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8fc164b28ad94d9b8fd564e426375a1a?version=3.55.1)